# se han bloqueado algunas imagenes para evitar que el remitente identifique su equipo

Tags: html, imagen, vscode, visual, bloqueo

tengo un problema con un bloqueo de imagenes. No se desde donde se estan bloqueando las imagenes que subo en VSCode creando un html, porque cuando quiero ver el html no las muestra con ningun navegador y el explorador de windows tampoco. Cuando pongo el "inspeccionar" dentro del navegador de internet me muestra "file not found" pero los archivos si existen y las rutas son correctas.

Adjunto captura del explorador de windows.
Aguardo comentarios.
Saludos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y apretaste arriba donde dice mostrarlas?

Comment: no pasa nada cuando clickeo en el mensaje